# Capture image frame from a video playing on an iframe

Tags: jquery, canvas, iframe

Is it possible to capture an image frame from a video playing inside an iframe?

I've found [this example](http://appcropolis.com/blog/web-technology/using-html5-canvas-to-capture-frames-from-a-video/) that show's that is possible to capture frames from a video using `HTML5` Canvas. But I would like to capture the frame from an external (hosted on another site) iframe.

Comment: If it's a cross domain iframe then it won't be possible to do this.